# Odoo How make entire form readonly when it moves to 'Quotaion Sent' State using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, readonly

I have inherited the Sale order form in my custom module. How make entire form readonly when it moves to 'Quotaion Sent' State using xpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your inherited `form view` you can make any field or group read-only by using `xpath` as follows.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('state','=','sent')]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```